# pytest gives error for numpy\testing\nosetester

Tags: python, python-2.7, pytest

I am new at using pytest. I am getting this error and don't know how to fix it.

[image]

Please help so that I get rid of this error? Thanks

Comment: Is your `def test(self, ...)` function part of a class? If not, you don't need the self keyword.

Comment: This is no function named def test(self, ...) in my program. It is actually in the nosetester.py file which is located in numpy\testing folder...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

py.test looks for all functions starting with the prefix "test" and executes them as such. My suggestion to you is to set a marker to the tests you actually want to run. Above each test definition, put something like `@pytest.mark.smoke` and add `-m smoke` when executing your tests from command line. Also, instead of specifying the file path of the file containing your tests, you can just give the directory's path.